# Policy based routing cause NAT not to work correctly

Tags: route, iproute

```
echo "200 rj45" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
echo "201 WIFI" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add default via 192.168.5.9 dev eth0
ip rule add from 192.168.5.8/24 table rj45
ip rule add from 192.168.61.128/24 table WIFI
ip route add default via 192.168.5.9 dev eth0 table rj45
ip route add default via 192.168.61.38 dev wlan0 table WIFI
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.196.0.0/16 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.196.0.0/16 -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
ip route flush cache
```

Hi.
The above commands are entered upon Linux server 1 bootup.

In **Linux server 1**, there are **3 interfaces**.
**2 interface** are **WAN** interface, **eth0** with **192.168.5.8/24** IP and **wlan0** **with 192.168.61.128/24** IP.
Another interface is **LAN** with **10.196.3.254/16** IP.

Linux server 1 eth0 is connected to **Linux server 2 eth0** with **192.168.5.9/24** IP.

The above policy route commands are implemented for Linux policy route.
Default route is rj45 but on some condition the default route is changed to WIFI.

I am facing a problem when the following NAT iptables commands doesn't take effect especially with the command **ip rule add from 192.168.5.8/24 table rj45** .
when the **client IP 10.196.3.253/16 ping 192.168.5.9 which is the subnet of Linux Server 1 eth0.**
If 10.196.3.253 ping 192.168.3.9 which Linux server 2 alias IP, it can ping.

tcpdump -i eth0 icmp at Linux server 2 shows that it try reply icmp ping of 10.196.3.253 which means the ICMP ping is most likely not NAT.
below is the output

```
12:31:14.519000 IP 192.168.5.8 > 192.168.5.9: ICMP echo request, id 4213, seq 155, length 64
12:31:14.519018 IP 192.168.5.9 > 192.168.5.8: ICMP echo reply, id 4213, seq 155, length 64
12:31:14.520018 IP 192.168.5.9 > 10.196.3.253: ICMP echo reply, id 4213, seq 155, length 64
```

Any idea why NAT doesn't work in this setup?
Below is the network diagram for clarity.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ip rule matches with a subnet id instead of an address, because you have the prefix length `/24` (instead of `/32` or omitted) there.

Prefix length like `/24` is only appropriate / necessary when you configure an IP on an interface, in which case it is used to signify the subnet mask/size. In other cases, you should not include it unless you actually want to match for a subnet (in that case you should use the correct address as well, e.g. `192.168.5.0` for `/24`).

While `192.168.5.8/24` isn't exactly valid / sensical as a subnet id, probably it result in `192.168.5.9` being covered by the rule anyway. Therefore, the "reverse DNAT'd" reply from `192.168.5.9` is routed/forwarded back to itself by the `default` route in `rj45` on Server 1, instead of being routed/forwarded to `10.196.3.253`.

Comment: Thanks Tom Yan for the prompt reply.
I didn't realise 192.168.5.8/24 was a subnet range for ip rule add till you point it.
That fix the issue of 10.196.3.253 can't ping 192.168.5.9.

However, after further testing, 10.196.3.253 can't ping 192.168.5.8 which is also Linux Server 1 WAN IP.

Seems either I would need to exclude the iptables MASQUERADE if destination IP is 192.168.5.8 and source IP is 10.196.0.0/16
or adding more ip rule. mmm.

Comment: Tested the command **iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.196.0.0/16 ! -d 192.168.5.8 -j MASQUERADE**
still doesn't allow client 10.196.3.253/16 to ping 192.168.5.8.

Comment: It's actually a problem of the same nature of the original one. You probably want to add a rule that lookup the `main` table that has lower priority / higher precedence and make use of the `suppress_prefixlength 0` magic (which ignores the `default` route in the `main` table in that lookup). Otherwise your other rules will "invalidate" all other routes in the `main` table you need.

Comment: I have tried the following  
1) **ip rule add from 10.196.0.0/16 to 192.168.5.8 table main** and ensure it is lower number = highest priority  
2a) **iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -s 10.196.0.0/16 -d 192.168.5.8 -j MARK --set-mark 1**
2b) **ip rule add fwmark 1 table main**

Both doesn't resolve the issue.

I thought it is due to packet from 10.196.0.0/16 to 192.168.5.8 is not using the main route?
I am still not sure whether suppress_prefixlength is required.

Comment: @Carve8851 The problem(s) you have been experiencing is about where the replies to `10.196.3.253` would be routed to. If you insist on having a `to`-match rule instead, the `to`-match should cover `10.196.3.253`. Same applies to the (fw)mark approach here. (Your approach does not involve "connmark".)

Comment: @Carve8851 You don't any extra match for the `suppress_prefixlength 0 lookup main` rule btw. And the reason you want it is because `default` routes are the only routes in your alternate route tables, and as per you descriptions, you don't seem to want the those `default` routes to override non-`default` routes in the `main` table. A (lower-priority) `suppress_prefixlength 0 lookup main` would suit you need precisely -- make sure non-`default` routes in the `main` table will be used, if any. (`default` is an alias of `0.0.0.0/0`, and the `0` after `/` is the prefix length.)